# How to Make Login API with Laravel 5.6 Passport from Different Table and Guard

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

How to make login API token with Laravel 5.6 passport from other table (visitors, not users) and different guard (visitor).

**Its working** when i use default laravel auth table (**users**), but i need login from **visitors** table.

this is my auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'visitor' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'visitors',
    ],

    'visitor-api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'visitors',
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'visitors' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Visitor::class,
    ],

],
```

And this my AuthControlloer for API

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string',
        'remember_me' => 'boolean'
    ]);

    if (!Auth::guard('visitor')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember))
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    $user = $request->user();
    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
    $token = $tokenResult->token;


    if ($request->remember_me)
        $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
    $token->save();
    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
            $tokenResult->token->expires_at
        )->toDateTimeString()
    ]);
}
```

This error message when i test in postman

```
"message": "Call to a member function createToken() on null",
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `$request->user()` will only retrieve the user for the default guard.

To get the user, instead you need to do `Auth::guard('visitor')->user()` to get the user.

You will then be able to call `createToken()` on the user, providing you have added the `HasApiTokens` trait to the model.

Comment: Make sure too, that your `App\Visitor` class implements the `Authenticatable` interface.

Comment: This is the best solution I found so far. Thank you very much.